# What happens if i allow a port in outbound rules?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

What happens if i allow a port in outbound rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Then, presumably, traffic will be allowed outbound on that port on whatever device this rule resides on.

For a more detailed answer, you're going to need to give a more detailed question.

Comment: well that isn't correct according to microsoft

Comment: @blumar - Citation please? This is pretty simple stuff, so I'd be surprised if I were wrong.

Comment: you are talking about inbound not outbound

Comment: /me goes into "don't feed the troll" mode.

Comment: the answer is: nothing happens, because by default windows server 2008 allows outgoing unless you block it. You are a troll.

Comment: now you can delete my answer like you people here usually do and put some artificial points to your fake knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Access from the Host -> Outbound (usually to the internet) through that port is allowed or blocked..

It can be considered good security to not only 
lock down inbound ports (External -> Internal)
but also
lock down outbound ports (Internal -> External)

Cheers

Comment: you people even know what outbound is ?

Comment: Ummm yes...
Perhaps you should explain your question with some more details..

Its easier for use to help you.

Comment: outgoing is a useless feature that doesn't makes any difference and i want to know why do why they build it inside a firewall, wouldn't be enough just to block stuff, i mean it is rather strange when you are helpless to protect yourself from unknown stuff. What is unknown you can block or can you ? Why would i want to allow it, its just useless and illogical.

Comment: @blumar, sounds like you need to do a bit more reading/research on security in depth. It is a longstanding best practice to use outbound firewall rules (on both network and host-based firewalls) to only allow traffic out that you really need.

Comment: i think you people don't know what i am talking about

Comment: because you don't know the difference between inbound and outbound or you would know what i am talking about

Comment: As a personal experience.. got hacked, due to a OPENSSH bug..
IRC server was set up on my server..
However, my hardware firewall was not blocking outgoing connections..
So they served 45 GB of traffic before i was notified..

I later installed an IDS and outgoing firewall rules.. Which automatically blocks outgoing traffic and DOS's my own server if it is doing strange things :D ( of course fixing the openSSH bug too )

Comment: yes i know that and this is what i am talking about, it is useless option that allow.

Comment: microsoft uses that outbound to steal data from your pc :)

Comment: and when you close your bios port another one appears

Comment: Ok.. i understand exactly what you mean...

The thing you clearly dont know.. is that another good security practice..
is to BLOCK ALL..and then slowly ALLOW just the ports you need..
This is why ALLOW is there.. because an intelligent program/hacker will just push through other open ports and collect the traffic with nc..

So you need to BLOCK ALL.. then ALLOW a few.. to do it right

However.. dont do this on a server, its annoying and too much to maintain ( get some firewall hardware or install something like pfSense)

Comment: i just don't understand why microsoft needs you to determine what you don't need, just too many tings you don't need that are opened

Comment: Use Mac OSX or Ubuntu is my suggestion :P

Comment: @Blumer - a BIOS port? Are you serious? I think you're the one that needs to research your terms...

Comment: Yes.. there is a little confusion here...

Comment: there is confusion why you people have soo many points and don't know what outbound rules are.

Comment: learn the basics and than you understand :)

Comment: Are you kidding???
I just explained to you why its necessary to have allows on outbound rules... Why are you not just accepting the answer, or at least giving more details to your question so it can be answered better???

Comment: basics of outbound(outgoing) = by default is allowed (any port, program) if it ain't blocked. That is why i asked the question, because....i know that you people don't know. :P

Comment: the answer to my question is simple: nothing happens

Comment: @blumar - if you intend to come here with the goal of asking deceptive questions, I'm fairly certain that you'll find yourself with a banned account in fairly short order. On the other hand, if you put a good faith effort into asking intelligent, well-articulated, and well-researched questions, you'll be quite surprised at the information that can be gleaned from SF. This will be my last correspondence on this question.